# How to inject external javascript code in phone browser

Tags: javascript, browser, console, mobile-browser

I would like to inject an external javascript code into a certain webpage in a mobile phone browser such as chrome or opera mini. On computers, we can do this directly in the console or through extensions such as Scripty. Unfortunately, phone browsers don't show consoles nor do they have extensions. Please how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [eruda](https://github.com/liriliri/eruda). It's a console for mobile browsers. It also has many plugins such as ***eruda-touches*** which visualizes all current touches and their positions.
Personally, I made a bookmark using chrome browser on my phone to implement this console directly in any page when i search for its name. Watch this youtube [video](https://youtu.be/4kkvFJS9F-g) for more details.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the address-bar to run javascript in that page.

(Tested in Chrome)

Like this:

[image: Step0]
[image: Step1]
[image: Step2]

Since all the codes will be in one line, make sure you use semicolons properly.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using android, then you can use chrome inspect to access console on phone browser using a computer.

1. First you should connect your phone to your computer via USB and authorize it.
2. In Chrome on your computer open the following link chrome://inspect
3. There you can see opened tabs on your mobile device, and open their console.